# Why does websocket have so many network connections and what do they mean?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm learning websockets, especially socket.io-client lib and I got confused with some things, I hope somebody can explain in details what I'm missing.

I'm creating socket connection globally, in a separate module and then import socket to the modules where I need to listen for events from server or emit some events to server.

When I opened network tab of my browser, I noticed multiple connections
[image]

When I check the response of each of these requests I see the following:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain me please what is going on on each stage?

Why in one request I get sid and nothing else and in the other request I get object with different sid and some additional data?

I'd be glad to read it somewhere if you can share some link, I just can't google such detailed explanation anywhere.

Thank you

Updated per request of @cassiolacerda adding screenshots of components where socket connection is done.

[image]

and here I listen to event "connect"
[image]

Comment: can you share your react component that shows the socket.connect() method?

Comment: thank you for your response. I updated the post body.